# How to show "Only 1 Product available" also on Configurable Product?

Tags: magento2, stock

Im wondering how I can "activate" the "Only X left Threshold" also for configurable products?
On Normal Products it works and shows for example "only 1 left", but on products where you can choose different colors or sizes, it doesnt work and nothings shows even if there are only 2 items left.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was looking for this too and I think it should show for configurable and it should be the total amount on it's child product combined e.g if i have 2 simple product as child of the configurable and each have *10* it should show *20* in total but as soon as a size/colour is selected it should change to reflect the qty left to the selected product in question.